# Set a max height on a .NET MessageBox

Tags: .net, window, messagebox

I use MessageBox.Show() with a huge text message, so the message window get out of the screen.
Does anyone know how to avoid this ugly behaviour by fixing the max height of the window ?

Comment: No, the `MessageBox` does not have any properties that are available to the developer to change it's size. Only the message, buttons and icons. You will need to create your own custom WinForm as the other answers state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure MessageBox is a fixed size.  Can use Window.ShowDialog() for a modal window.

Comment: Effectively, it seems that there is no way to set the MessageBox height. But i just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom form to display custom size MessageBox.

I know you have WinForms but I did that in my WPF project.

Comment: Sure, but I just want to know if it's possible to custom a bit the MessageBox using options.